# User or role does not exist in the database

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to locally install a CMS for my website. During this installation process, it shows me an error "User or role does not exist in the database.
Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Here's the screenshot of the database properties from Management Studio.
[image]

How can I add a new role or user to this database?

Comment: I haven't got SQL Express. Is there a "Security" node in the treeview? If so expand that to do that through the GUI.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to an existing database?

Comment: @Martin: Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/7M6id.jpg What do I need to change from here?

Comment: Your screenshot is showing server logins - expand the database for database users.

Comment: Oh got it! I What permissions I need to give in this? http://i.imgur.com/9FKfa.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within SQL Server Management Studio

1. Expand the Security node
2. Right-click the Logins node and select New Login...
3. Provide a login name and password (SQL authentication) or a logon name only if using Windows authentication.
4. Click User Mapping in the "Select a page" box on the left.
5. Check the database dbemployee in the list.
6. Grant the appropriate security in the database role membership.

Hit OK and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am only able to grant permissions for public and db_owner. For the rest, it's showing some error like "Cannot relate to principal dbo". Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ubPAe.jpg

Comment: Granting public and db_owner should be sufficient although for a production website, I'd recommend not granting db_owner and instead granting the absolute minimum the site will function with.